# The object passed as the value prop to the Context provider changes every render. How to Fix it with useMemo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following problem,
The object passed as the value prop to the Context provider (at line 20) changes every render. To fix this consider wrapping it in a useMemo hook.
I don't know hot to use useMemo in this case. So how do I fix it?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Context from './Context';

function Provider({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDataAPI = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://swapi-trybe.herokuapp.com/api/planets/');
      const dataAPI = await response.json();
      const alteredData = dataAPI.results.map(({ residents, ...params }) => params);
      const result = [...alteredData];
      setData(result.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));
    };
    getDataAPI();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={ { data } }>
      { data[0] && children }
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

Provider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default Provider;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are passing:

```
value={ { data } }
```

It is an object `{data : data}`. This is defined everytime.

You better pass `value={data}` and change your useContext hooks accordingly in children